# How to know wheter or not is possible to solve an equations explicitly

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

On an assignment I got the following question:

> Characterize the this DE: $$\frac{1}{4x^2}(y')^2+\frac{x}{2}y'-y=0 $$

My suggested solution is: It is a first order, non-linear, ordinary differential equation. I am not sure whether it is implicit or explicit. In our textbook, an implicit differential equation is defined as:

> **Implicit**:  is not possible to express $y^{(n)}$ explicitly  as a function of $y^{(n-1)},...,y$.

So, my question essentially comes down to:

1. Is it possible to write quadratic equation in $y'$ in an explicit form. I know the solution formula but there is this $\pm$. Is this $\pm$ allowed in an explicit function?
2. **How do I know in general whether or not an implicit expression can be rearranged to yield an explicit function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quadratic equation for $y'$.  Quadratics are not one-to-one.  Therefore there is no single expression for $y'$ in terms of $y$ and $x$. $\pm$ means not one expression but two.

Comment: Thanks, but how to know in general, whether an expression can be rearranged into an explicit function?
Also, I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function
There it says that explicit solutions can be found for quadratic, cubic and quartic functions. This does not agree with what you wrote, does it? Could you maybe clarify this to me?

Comment: The problem is not the "explicit", it's the "as a function of".